# Converting List[Option[A]] to an Option[List[A]] in Scala

Tags: scala

I am new to FP and Scala and am reading the book Functional Programming in Scala. One of the exercises in Chapter 4 asks us to write a function called `sequence` which would convert a `List[Option[A]]` to an `Option[List[A]]`. Here `Option` is a reimplementation of the `Option` provided by the Scala library. Here's the required code.

```
trait Option[+A] {
    /* Function to convert Option[A] to Option[B] using the function passed as an argument */
    def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] = this match {
        case None => None
        case Some(v) => Some(f(v))
    }

    /* Function to get the value in `this` option object or return the default value provided. Here,
     * `B >: A` denotes that the data type `B` is either a super-type of `A` or is `A`
     */
    def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B = this match {
        case None => default
        case Some(v) => v
    }

    /* Used to perform (nested) operations on `this` and aborts as soon as the first failure is
     * encountered by returning `None`
     */
    def flatMap[B](f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] = {
        map(f).getOrElse(None)
    }
}

case class Some[+A](get: A) extends Option[A]   // used when the return value is defined
case object None extends Option[Nothing]        // used when the return value is undefined
```

Now I tried a lot, but I had to look up the solution for writing `sequence`, which is,

```
def sequence[A](l: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = l match {
    case Nil => Some(Nil)                   // Or `None`. A design decision in my opinion
    case h :: t => h.flatMap(hh => sequence(t).map(hh :: _))
}
```

I just want to make sure I understood the solution correctly. So here are my questions.

1. Is my intuition about the return value for `case Nil` correct? Is it really a design decision or is one way better than the other?
2. For `case h :: t`, this is what I understood. We pass the value `h` firstly to the anonymous function in `flatMap` (as `hh`) which invokes `sequence` recursively. This recursive call of `sequence` returns an `Option` encapsulating the `Option`s in `t`. We invoke `map` on this returned value and pass `h` to the anonymous function (as `hh`) which then creates a new `List[A]` with the list returned by the recursive call as the tail and `h` as the head. This value is then encapsulated in `Option` by invoking `Some` and returned.

Is my understanding for the the second part correct? If yes, is there a better way to explain it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `sequence` is intended to return `None` if any element in the list is `None`, and return `Some` of values in the list otherwise.  So your intuition about the `Nil` case is not correct -- `Nil` is an empty list that contains no `None`s, so the result should not be `None`.

Let's take it one step at a time, from the inside out.

Suppose we have some variable `optionList`of type `Option[List[A]]` and some variable `a` of type `A`.  What do we get when we call:

```
optionList.map(a :: _)
```

If `optionList` is `None`, then this will be `None`.  If `optionList` contains a list, say `list`, this will be `Some(a :: list)`.

Now if for some variable `option` of type `Option[A]`, what do we get when we call:

```
option.flatMap(a => optionList.map(a :: _))
```

If `option` is `None`, then this will be `None`.  If `option` contains a value, say `a`, then this will be `optionList.map(a :: _)`, which we figured out above (by the definition of `flatMap`).

Now if we tie it together, we see that if any element is `None`, then the recursive call is avoided and the whole result will be `None`.  If no element is `None`, then the recursive call will keep appending the element's values, and the result will be `Some` of the list's element's internal values.

It might be more clearer if you rewrite the inner part:

```
def sequence[A](l: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = l match {
    case Nil => Some(Nil)
    case h :: t => h match {
        case None => None
        case Some(head) => sequence(t) match {
            case None => None
            case Some(list) => Some(head :: list)
        }
    }
}
```

Or even less idiomatic, but maybe clarifying:

```
def sequence[A](l: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = l match {
    case Nil => Some(Nil)
    case h :: t => 
        val restOfList = sequence(t)
        if (h == None || restOfList == None) None else Some(h.get :: restOfList.get)
}
```

You could also rewrite this pretty naturally as a `fold` without recursion, in case that is what's confusion you:

```
def sequence[A](l: List[Option[A]]) = (Option(List.empty[A]) /: l) {
    case(Some(sofar), Some(value)) => Some(value :: sofar); 
    case(_, _) => None 
}
```

Comment: The problem with the `fold` version is that the resulting List doesn't maintain order;  it becomes reversed.

Comment: You want to use `sofar :+ value` in place of `value :: sofar` in the case statement to append to the end of list so far.

Comment: @borice Wold using `foldRight` fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I think I was trying to solve same question from the same book and came up with this. It works for me and looks pretty clear and consice

```
def sequence[A](a: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = {

  a.foldLeft(Option(List[A]())) {

    (prev, cur) => {

      for {
        p <- prev if prev != None
        x <- cur
      } yield x :: p

    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Tail-Recursive* Solution

```
def seqToOption[T](s: Seq[Option[T]]): Option[Seq[T]] = {
  @tailrec
  def seqToOptionHelper(s: Seq[Option[T]], accum: Seq[T] = Seq[T]()): Option[Seq[T]] = {
    s match {
      case Some(head) :: Nil => Option(head +: accum)
      case Some(head) :: tail => seqToOptionHelper(tail, head +: accum)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
  seqToOptionHelper(s)
}
```

Original answer: [Need to convert Seq[Option[A]] to Option[Seq[A]]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52547572/3679900)

Comment: This reverses the original order if the sequence

Answer (score 0):

Converting `List[Option[A]]` to `Option[List[A]]` using `foldLeft`:

```
def optionSequence[A](loa: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] =
    loa
      .foldLeft(Option(List.empty[A]))((ol, v) =>
          (ol, v) match {
          case (None, _) | (_, None) => None
          case (Some(l), Some(av))   => Some(av :: l)
      })
      .map(_.reverse)
```

Since `List` is a linked list, prepending is faster than appending. This is why I am prepending the values to the final list and then reversing the list (using the `map`) to preserve the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `l` is a `List[Option[A]]` here is another approach using `partition` and `isEmpty`.

```scala
l.partition(_.isEmpty) match {
  case (Nil, x) => Some(x.map(_.get))
  case _        => None
}
```

Note that when given an empty list it will return `Some(List())`.  If `None` is desired adding another case is straightforward:

```scala
l.partition(_.isEmpty) match {
  case (Nil, Nil) => None
  case (Nil, x)   => Some(x.map(_.get))
  case _          => None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from `Future.sequence` which ostensibly does the same transformation for an `IterableOnce` of `Future`s, here is an adapted implementation for `Option`s.

This also has the benefit of using implicit collection builders, meaning that it is collection type independent.

```
final def sequence[A, CC[X] <: IterableOnce[X], To](in: CC[Option[A]])(implicit bf: BuildFrom[CC[Option[A]], A, To]): Option[To] = {
  in.iterator
    .foldLeft(Option(bf.newBuilder(in))) {
      (b, a) => {
        b.flatMap(builder => a.map(builder.addOne))
      }
    }
    .map(_.result())
}
```

The only negative of this implementation is that it will not exit on the first `None` encountered but instead traverse the whole iteration.