# Need to convert a Seq[Option[A]] to Option[Seq[A]]

Tags: scala, fold, scala-option

**USE CASE**

I have a list of files that can might have a valid mime type or not.
In my code, I represent this using an Option.

I need to convert a Seq[Option[T]] to Option[Seq[T]] so that I do not process the list if some of the files are invalid.

**ERROR**

This is the error in the implementation below:

```
found   : (Option[Seq[A]], Option[A]) => Option[Seq[A]]
[error]  required: (Option[Any], Option[Any]) => Option[Any]
[error]     s.fold(init)(liftOptionItem[A])
```

**IMPLEMENTATION**

```
def liftOptionItem[A](acc: Option[Seq[A]], itemOption: Option[A]): Option[Seq[A]] = {
    {
      acc match {
        case None => None
        case Some(items) =>
          itemOption match {
            case None => None
            case Some(item) => Some(items ++ Seq(item))
          }
      }
    }
  }

  def liftOption[A](s: Seq[Option[A]]): Option[Seq[A]] = {
    s.fold(Some(Seq()))(liftOptionItem[A])
  }
```

This implementation returns `Option[Any]` instead of `Option[Seq[A]` as the type of the `liftOptionItem[A]` does not fit in.

Comment: this seems a duplicate topic to a stackerflow, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753777/converting-listoptiona-to-an-optionlista-in-scala concept is the same than here....

Comment: @legramira thanks. Could you close this question as a duplicate, thanks. Aologies for not searching before asking this question

Comment: `Some(acc.map(_.get))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting List\[Option\[A\]\] to an Option\[List\[A\]\] in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753777/converting-listoptiona-to-an-optionlista-in-scala)

Answer (score 5):

If you use TypeLevel Cats:

```
import cats.implicits._

List(Option(1), Option(2), Option(3)).traverse(identity)
```

Returns:

```
Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3))
```

You have to use `List` so use a `toList` first:

```
Seq(Option(1), Option(2), Option(3)).toList.traverse(identity).map(_.toSeq)
```

Comment: Where do I import from or how do I declare `identity`?

Comment: @NefedovEfim, `identity` is automatic from `Predef` which is automatically imported in Scala. So all you need is `import cats.implicits._`. If anything perhaps you may need to qualify the traverse, `Seq(Option(1), Option(2), Option(3)).toList.traverse[Option, Int](identity).map(_.toSeq)` but that's all you need, and of course, install cats into your project. ;)

Answer (score 3):

using scalaz:

```
import scalaz._
import Sclaza._

val x:List[Option[Int]] = List(Option(1))
x.sequence[Option, Int] //returns Some(List(1))

val y:List[Option[Int]] = List(None, Option(1))
y.sequence[Option, Int] // returns None
```

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to use functional libraries like cats or Scalaz you could use a foldLeft

```
def seqToOpt[A](seq: Seq[Option[A]]): Option[Seq[A]] =
    seq.foldLeft(Option(Seq.empty[A])){
        (res, opt) =>
          for {
            seq <- res
            v <- opt
          } yield seq :+ v
      }
```

Comment: See here for a collection type agnostic version of this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71603797/1368854

Answer (score 0):

Tail-recursive Solution: It returns None if any one of the seq element is None.

```
def seqToOption[T](s: Seq[Option[T]]): Option[Seq[T]] = {
  @tailrec
  def seqToOptionHelper(s: Seq[Option[T]], accum: Seq[T] = Seq[T]()): Option[Seq[T]] = {
    s match {
      case Some(head) :: Nil => Option(head +: accum)
      case Some(head) :: tail => seqToOptionHelper(tail, head +: accum)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
  seqToOptionHelper(s)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with `None` in case statements is the reason for returning the `Option[Seq[Any]] type` in stead of `Option[Seq[A]] type`. We need to make the function
`liftOptionItem[A]` to return `Option[Seq[Any]] type`. And the compilation error can be fixed with the following changes in both the functions.(Because `fold` does not go in any particular order, there are constraints on the `start value` and thus `return value` , the `foldLeft` is used in stead of `fold`.)

```
 def liftOptionItem[A](acc: Option[Seq[Any]], itemOption: Option[A]): Option[Seq[Any]] = {
     {
       acc match {
         case None => Some(Nil)
         case Some(items)=>
           itemOption match {
             case None => Some(items ++ Seq("None"))
             case Some(item) => Some(items ++ Seq(item))
           }
       }
     }
   }

 def liftOption[A](s: Seq[Option[A]]): Option[Seq[Any]] = {
   s.foldLeft(Option(Seq[Any]()))(liftOptionItem[A])
 }
```

Now, code compiles.

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> val list1 = Seq(None,Some(21),None,Some(0),Some(43),None)
list1: Seq[Option[Int]] = List(None, Some(21), None, Some(0), Some(43), None)

scala> liftOption(list1)
res2: Option[Seq[Any]] = Some(List(None, 21, None, 0, 43, None))

scala> val list2 = Seq(None,Some("String1"),None,Some("String2"),Some("String3"),None)
list2: Seq[Option[String]] = List(None, Some(String1), None, Some(String2), Some(String3), None)

scala> liftOption(list2)
res3: Option[Seq[Any]] = Some(List(None, String1, None, String2, String3, None))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no really "beautiful" way to make this with out scalaz or cats.
But you can try something like this.

```
def seqToOpt[A](seq: Seq[Option[A]]): Option[Seq[A]] = {
  val flatten = seq.flatten
  
  if (flatten.isEmpty) None
  else Some(flatten)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't return `None` if the seq contains a combination of `Some` and `None`