# Convert Scala `Seq[Option[A]]` to `Option[Seq[A]]`

Tags: scala, functional-programming, option-type

I'm wondering what the idiomatic way in Scala would be to convert a `Seq` of `Option[A]` to an `Option[Seq[A]]`, where the result is `None` if any of the input options were `None`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753777/converting-listoptiona-to-an-optionlista-in-scala and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52546860/need-to-convert-a-seqoptiona-to-optionseqa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic way is probably to use what is generally called `traverse`.

I'd recommend reading Cats' documentation about it: https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/traverse.html

With Cats, it would be as easy as:

```scala
import cats.implicits

val list = List(Some(1), Some(2), None)
// list: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), Some(2), None)

val traversed = list.traverse(identity)
// traversed: Option[List[Int]] = None

// Or in this specific case:
val sequenced = list.sequence
// sequenced: Option[List[Int]] = None
```

Answer (score 3):

Standard library provides [`partitionMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#partitionMap%5BA1,A2%5D(f:A=%3EEither%5BA1,A2%5D):(CC%5BA1%5D,CC%5BA2%5D)) which helps implement `sequence` operation

```
_.partitionMap(_.toRight("")) match {
  case (Nil, xs) => Some(xs)
  case _ => None
}
```

Here is a possible generic implementation as extension method

```
extension [CC[x] <: IterableOps[x, CC, CC[x]], A](xs: CC[Option[A]])
  def sequence: Option[CC[A]] =
    xs.partitionMap(_.toRight("")) match {
        case (lefts, as) if lefts.isEmpty => Some(as)
        case _ => None
    }
```

Comment: Very nice, but use of `Nil` restricts the possible collection types. Alternative: `.pipe(tup => if (tup._1.isEmpty) Some(tup._2) else None)`